# Как получить ответ от post запроса, посланного через html

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Мне нужно следующее:
1. `button` отправляет данные на сервер через post-запрос

2. Проверяется наличие совпадений с переменной `$login` в базе данных в столбце `login` - если совпадения есть, то возвращается первичный ключ в переменную $end
3. Если $end пустая - то пользователя не перенаправляет в свой профиль, он остаётся на той же странице и ему показывается оповещение о том, что логин не зарегистрирован.

Как реализовать последнюю часть? Нужно что бы пользователь остался на той же странице, но появилось оповещение.

Код:

```
$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$login = stripslashes($login);
$login = htmlspecialchars($login);
$login = trim($login);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$password = htmlspecialchars($password);
$password = trim($password);
$db = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "testsite", "testsite", "LHVideo");
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT id FROM accounts WHERE login = '$login'");
$array = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$end = $array['id'];
$error = mysqli_error($db);
if(emtpy($end)){
    //Тут что писать?
mysqli_close($db);
exit();
```

Comment: Если конкретнее - как сделать это оповещение? Как оставить пользователя на странице я догадываюсь

Comment: Нужен код запроса и верстки

Comment: Оповещение делается на стороне клиента. PHP должен возвращать некоторые данные которые позволяют понять был ли вход удачным. А js должен их получить и выдать сообщение если вход неудачный.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если хотите получить ответ, нужно ajax использовать.

Можно перенаправить с помощью функции header попробовать, а данные сохранить в сессию, но это не будет так удобно для пользователя.

В общем перенаправте пользователя обратно, а в сессию сообщение сохранить. Дальше уже JavaScript